# How to use native library

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

For example, I have a C++ library which was called `HelperLib`. I have some assumptions:

1. I can compile this project into *so file. (by some tutorial online that help me build this library on Android).
2. I can use this library in C/C++. By official tutorial on library's website.
3. I have a basic knowledge about native library. For example, loading a native library using `System.loadlibrary()`, calling simple native C function for example.

Those assumptions I often meet when decide to use some C++ libraries online. They provide tutorials how to use, and some other provide how to build this library on Android.

But with all of these, I still cannot figure out how to use this library on Android. Where to start? Which should I do more, before I can use this library? For example.

```
///// this is a C++ source file to use library
int main() {
   HelperLib lib = new HelperLib(); // just for example
   lib.initialize();
   /// demo how this library was used
   lib.makeConnection();
   lib.closeConnection();
   return 0;
}
```

Based on the above code, can I port it to Android layer and how? Does it simple by calling `line-by-line` function as C++ example? Or we must do "something else" ? This makes me confuse many times, when many people say "tutorial port library to Android", but not provide a useful way to invoke library function.

Please help me, with above assumptions, how can I continue to use this library. Are there any tutorials online to help me on this problems?

Thanks :)

Comment: Search for something called JNI-  Java Native Interface.  It lets java call C++.  You need to write JNI wrappers in C or C++ for the functions you want to call, then call them via matching native Java functions.  But a full tutorial is beyond the scope of SO

Comment: @GabeSechan I can search and learn in those tutorials. But after that, what should I do next? I just simple make a JNI Wrapper, after that call line-by-line as C++ example source code, right ? I don't sure in this step. Please tell me. Thanks :)

Comment: A tutorial on JNI will tell you what to do on the Java and C side.  But yes, once both sides are done its as simple as calling a function.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://www.kandroid.org/ndk/docs/CPU-FEATURES.html), it might be useful for reference

Comment: Just a remark: You could add a link to those tutorial you have used, it may be useful for other users

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's as straightforward as [@Gabe Sechan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1631193/) has already mentioned in the comments.

> 1.I can compile this project into *so file. (by some tutorial online that help me build this library on Android).

You will need to add the JNI wrapper to the native library. For e.g., wrapper.cpp:

```
HelperLib lib;

void Java_com_example_hqt_MainActivity_initialize() {
    lib = new HelperLib();
    lib.initialize();
}

void Java_com_example_hqt_MainActivity_makeConnection() {
    lib.makeConnection();
}
```

And then

> 3.I have a basic knowledge about native library. For example, loading a native library using System.loadlibrary(), calling simple native C function for example.

That's, in MainActivity.java:

```
static {
    Log.d(TAG, "loadLibrary");
    System.loadLibrary("mynativelibrary");
}

public static native void initialize();
public static native void makeConnection();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Init native library
    initialize();
}

public void makeNativeConnection() {
    makeConnection();
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: as example above, MainActivity.java should put into package `java.com.example.hqt` ? thanks :)

Comment: Nope, not `java.com.example.hqt`. In the above example, the Android app's [package name](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#package) should be `com.example.hqt` -> `com.example.hqt.MainActivity`

Comment: thanks. so as above, i must add a wrapper for library. and this often doesn't provide with libary itself. So, I must write c++ wrapper code, after that i must re-write Makefile to compile those file, right ? thanks :)