# How to use an external .so

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm developing a simple Android app in Kotlin using Android Studio.
I have an external .so file which was written in C++, I don't have the source code of this .so but I have the header file .h.

My problem is that I'm not able to access the functions contained in the .so. I was reading a lot of topics about this but I'm not able to make it work.

Basically I would like to use 2 functions from the .so : init() and getVersion(). The problem is that the init() function takes 2 parameters which I don't know clearly how to declare in Kotlin:

```
//This is the .h in C++
typedef void (*AttachCurrentThreadToJNI)();
typedef void (*DetachCurrentThreadToJNI)();

sint32 init(char *myID, AttachCurrentThreadToJNI attach, DetachCurrentThreadToJNI detach);
sint32 getVersion(void);
```

In Kotlin I load the library this way:

```
//This is the Kotlin code
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    System.loadLibrary("myExternalLibrary");
```

After loading the library, how can I access the functions init() and getVersion() from my .so file ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be exactly the same as in Java which you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24400381/how-to-use-native-library).
Make sure to load the library from a companion object.

Comment: So as I understand :
1. I have to create a new .cpp file to make a wrapper, is it correct? Can I do that without having the original .cpp file? Should I add this file to my kotlin project?
2. I have to declare the methods in MainActivity.kt to be able to access them

- What do you mean about loading the library from a Companion Object?
- How I can declare my init() function in Kotlin? It is particular because the parameters are typedef, I read there is no equivalent in Java.

Comment: For using JNI with kotlin you can see the sample here: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/kotlin-app/hello-jni-kotlinApp

Comment: For binding external .so library see example (in Java) here: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/hello-libs.

Comment: Together it should give you all the info

Comment: Thank you, your 2 links were very helpful. But I still miss 1 piece of the puzzle: in my case I have "myExternalLibrary.so" without the C++ source file. I see in the examples that I need a wrapper to call the functions of the library, but there is no example on how to do that when I just have the .so file without .cpp source.

Comment: The second example (hello-libs) is wrapping 2 libraries - gmath.a and gperf.so without cpp files.

Comment: Yes but functions from gperf and gmath are never called directly from Kotlin, so there is no example how to do this. For me it is not clear how I should write the wrapper: should it be a new .cpp class ? a java class ?

Comment: They are called from hello-libs.cpp and hello-libs.cpp is called from Java so you need to wrap them in hello-libs.cpp.